# OpenGL: VBO and a broken GC

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I have recently tried the use of `VBO`. I just copy pasted the code from this [site](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/hellotriangle.html)

It compiles fine and seems running well. However, I noticed on the `taskmanager` that the program runs at 50% CPU usage. Its just a simple triangle, nothing else. I was expecting it to be of 0% because all of other programs I created in `glfw3` runs on 0% when idle. I know that V-SYNC in `glfw3` is set true by default, but still I add this line of code to ensure `glfwSetInterval(GL_TRUE); //sets V-SYNC on` but still nothings changed.

After messing with the `test_vs.glsl` (I think this has nothing to do with the problem):

code I changed:

**from**

```
#version 400

in vec3 vp;

void main ()
{
    gl_Position = vec4 (vp, 1.0);
}
```

**to**

```
#version 400

in vec2 vp;

void main ()
{
    gl_Position = vec4 (vp, 0, 1.0);
}
```

And changed attributes of vertex in `.cpp` code to 2D.

Running several times the `Hello Triangle` program again, computer stops and hang a bit ---> Then **CRAASSH**. The graphics card is broken! (literally ouch). The computer shutdowns itself, and I try rebooting it again, I got a screen with full of random lines displaying and fail to continue on desktop.

I don't have much of the information about the graphics card but `glew` says `GeForce 7300 GT/PCI/SSE2/3DNOW!` and running on `Windows XP` with `OpenGL v2.1` support according to `glew`.

Some of the extensions I added:

- `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);`
- `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE, 2);`
- `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;`
- And I add the prefix `ARB` to any function related to `vbo`

I suspect this is due to lack of `OpenGL extensions support check` (*this is just an assumption only and it is the most likely be the cause I can think of*). But, is that so really the problem? Is it the simple program or other? If so, why would they let this to happen?

Comment: Well, the problem here seems that your question is more of a tech issue than a programming issue. Sounds like a driver bug or something, I doubt a simple OpenGL program could have crashed your computer on its own.

Comment: @mebob I don't think this is fitted on `superuser` because it is much relevant to programming.

Comment: Suggestions to migrate this to `superuser` or other?

Comment: Are you checking `GLGeterror`?

Comment: @zero298 No I haven't.

Comment: @mr5 Put them everywhere and tell us what they say.

Comment: This SO gets me really down and discouraged every time I ask a question. I don't understand.

Comment: @mr5 Its OK, they just have the highest standards in the world. Don't get discouraged.

Comment: @BWG Thanks for cheering. I guess it's because of my grammar used in here.

Comment: Yes, this has absolutely nothing to do with the code you changed. I will let you in on a little secret - vertex attributes are ***always*** `vec4` no matter what size you use for in `glVertexAttribPointer (...)`. GL automatically assigns any missing component this way: `vec4 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. So a 1D vertex attribute is actually: `vec4 (X, 0, 0, 1)`. You change absolutely nothing by re-declaring said attribute `float` instead of `vec4`, you really just make life more difficult on yourself. **Long** story short, if you write `in vec4 vp;` you can drop this madness: `vec4 (vp, 0.0, 1.0)`!

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes, I feel it; that gl shader is smart and does that. What I'm actually quite concern of is about why it had been crashed that way and actually breaks the hardware.

Comment: By the way, if you have an OpenGL 2.1 implementation then the syntax in that shader is all wrong to begin with. You are limited to GLSL 1.20, and `in` and `out` for varyings were only introduced in GLSL 1.30 (OpenGL 3.0). Furthermore, you cannot create a core profile context on GL 2.1 hardware - core was only introduced in OpenGL 3.2. And finally, you need a `#version` directive at the top of your shader. A good GLSL compiler will warn you that the syntax is not supported in GLSL 1.10, which is what GLSL compilers are supposed to assume if you do not use `#version`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I omit the other part of `glsl` and I think I don't have any syntax error there for I can see the display output(triangle). Also worth mentioning that other things. Maybe some really bad thing just happened under the core because of the fancy stuffs I put.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I added the omitted code for clarity.

Comment: Ehh, I just want to mention that **the GeForce 7300 does not support OpenGL-4**; heck it doesn't even cover full OpenGL-3 support. Whatever is going on, the GPU most likely is not involved. So writing a `#version 400` shader will not work on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention that **the GeForce 7300 does not support OpenGL-4**; heck it doesn't even cover full OpenGL-3 support. Whatever is going on, the GPU most likely is not involved. So writing a `#version 400` shader will not work with lest even on your GPU.